# Remove element from vector, while storing the removed element

Tags: c++, vector

Trying to remove an element by index from a vector, while storing it to return it. How do I store the element's value in a way that is not deleted when I delete the element by index from the vector?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How could it get deleted?

Comment: Copy the element first.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, the value that you want to return needs to live somewhere, so if you remove the value from the `vector` you'll need to put it somewhere. Here's one option:

```
 /* Move the object out of the vector so that we can return it. */
 ObjectType result = std::move(myVector[myIndex]);

 /* Delete the value from the vector. */
 myVector.erase(myVector.begin() + myIndex); // Or equivalent

 return result;
```